# Show the following set is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, connectedness

For any $x \in \Bbb R^n$ how do I show that the set
$B_x := \{{kx\mid k \in \Bbb R}$} is connected.
It should also be concluded that $\Bbb R^n$ is connected.
I was thinking of starting by assuming that the set is not connected.Then there exist $U,V$ relatively open such that $\varnothing =U \cap V$ and $E=U \cup V$??

Answer (score 6):

Hint: the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected. Consider $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(k)=kx$.

Comment: how do I show $B_x$ is path connected. @egreg

Comment: @user123 Do you need to?

Comment: But how do I show it is connected? @egreg I was thinking that if path-connected then connected.Is there any other way?

Comment: @user123 Since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, the image of $f$ is connected; since the image of $f$ is precisely $B_x$, you are done.

Comment: What is f then if image of f is $B_x$? @egreg and this way it is too for granted shouldn't it be proven that the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected?

Comment: @user123 That the image of $f$ is $B_x$ is obvious. That $f$ is continuous is very easy to prove. That the image of a connected set under a continuous map is connected is the most fundamental fact about connectedness.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that $B_x$ is path-connected, hence connected. Also: $$\Bbb R^n  = \bigcup_{x \in \Bbb R^n}B_x, \quad \bigcap_{x \in \Bbb R^n}B_x = \{0\} \neq \varnothing.$$Hence...

Answer (score 1):

Prove that it is path-connected by proving that every point in $B_x$ is path-connected with $\vec 0$.